# Не заходит по порту на web интерфейс развернутый в docker

Tags: docker

Нашел aapanel в контейнере docker ( https://hub.docker.com/r/aapanel/aapanel ). По идеи при запуске этого контейнера

`sudo docker run -d -p 8886:8888 -p 22:21 -p 443:443 -p 80:80 -p 889:888 -v ~/website_data:/www/wwwroot -v ~/mysql_data:/www/server/data -v ~/vhost:/www/server/panel/vhost aapanel/aapanel:lib`

на моем ноутбуке (ubuntu 20.04) при переходе по ссылке http://192.168.0.2:8886 должен открыться веб интерфейс aapanel. Но пишет что ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Что я делаю не то? Что посмотреть?

Comment: а вы логи контейнера проверяли?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8886 открывается?

Comment: Exploding Kitten логов нет, системные только.

Comment: 127.0.0.1:8886 не открывает

Comment: наверно что то с контейнером, службы не запущены, ps aux 3 процесса.